# Dynamodb GetItem with contains

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm facing an issue with dynamodb, I'm new to this and it seems so hard to understand... while it seems "easy" with SQL
I hope you will be able to help me understand what I'm missing :) 
I have some information, like this:

```
Role
- identifier (hash)
- label 

User
- identifier (hash)
- label
- roleIdentifierList (each role is a different user... I don't like this, but that's the only way to get a range here I guess)

Item
- identifier (hash)
- roleIdentifier (global secondary index)
- label
```

How, with an "user identifier" and an "item identifier" could I be sure that this user has the correct role? 
I'm afraid my tables aren't well formed but documentation seems a little bit light.

Thanks!

I'm currently doing a scan on `User` to get all roles of user with identifier 
Then, I've try (but without success because we can't use "contains" with `getItem`) to retrieve the item with the correct id and at the same time check if there is the correct role. 
Is this correct to do a `getItem` and then in another logic rule (not related with dynamodb), check if the role is present?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into your datamodel and access patterns, the simple answer is for you to use `Query` API, which will allow you to provide a `FilterExpression` where you can use `contains`.

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name my-table-name \
--key-condition-expression "#pk = :pk" \
--filter-expression "contains(#y, :y)" \
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":y": { "S": "some identiier" }, ":pk": { "S": "abc" }}' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#y":"some attribute name", "#pk":"identifier"}'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html